# Apps keep crashing after OS X update

Tags: macos, safari, crash, spotlight

I've just updated my MBP 13'' mid 2010 to OS X 10.10.5 (14F27).
I remember that the last update was iTunes 12.2.2.25.

After this update, Mac rebooted and installed all the features.

Now I'm unable to open a lot of applications because they always crash.
I'm trying to figure out what is happening.

I've already tried to:

- Repair disk and disk permission.
- Run [OnyX](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html) to delete all the caches and indexes to rebuild them.

Nothing solved my issue.

Here some crash reports: [Safari](http://pastebin.com/iApijqYW), [Dash](http://pastebin.com/AwPTxzDS), [Mail](http://pastebin.com/yx0piNi1), [Dashboard](http://pastebin.com/B6ym3g1K), [ClipMenu](http://pastebin.com/qWRBYZY1), [Spotlight](http://pastebin.com/ufUS7NKA).

It seems that all this problem are related to web component.
Now I'm posting this answer using Google Chrome on the same Mac, and it works fine.

In Safe Mode here is the crash report of [Safari](http://pastebin.com/wZ9werTe) which quit unexpectedly while using WebCore plug-in.

Comment: here is what they have in common "webcore" and "webkit" !

Comment: Good, any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I've fixed it.
I made this steps:

1. Restore `/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/` from a Time Machine backup.

   - This fixed all the crashes but now is quite impossible to close Safari tabs or the program itself.
2. Reinstall OS X 10.10.5 update. It is available for download [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1833?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) or [here as combo update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1832).

   - This fixed everything.
   - As mentioned below in comment, the combo updater runs checks and balances for every update between the 10.10.0 and the current version. This is the best solution.

I think that is sufficient to perform only the step 2.

Comment: Re 2 - it's always better to use the relevant combo updater, rather than the delta, for this type of fix. It runs checks & balances for every update between the .0 & current. [10.10.5 combo update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1832)